# select rows where column values differ by more than two years

Tags: mysql, sql

So my table have such a records

```
ID    PRODUCT      MAKE_DATE       ORDER_DATE
1       aaaa       2010-11-04      2051-12-11 16:13:43
2       bbb        2011-10-05      2010-11-11 00:00:00
3       cccc       2010-05-20      0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

My Question: How to show those results where `make_date` is different than `order_date` for 2 years?

IM stuck at this:

```
Select ID, Product, make_date, order_datetime
FROM `tbl_order`
WHERE make_date ??? order_datetime
```

Result should be:

```
1       aaaa       2010-11-04      2051-12-11 16:13:43
3       cccc       2010-05-20      0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: I've assumed MySQL because of the backticks. Please correct the tag if this is wrong.

Comment: Why does the `ID=3` row appear in the results?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that make_date should be smaller or bigger than order_datetime for 2years. Thats the reason why results should show ID =1(smaller than 41year) and ID=3(bigger than 2010years)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select ID, Product, make_date, order_datetime
FROM tbl_order
WHERE make_date < order_datetime - INTERVAL 2 YEAR 
   OR make_date > order_datetime + INTERVAL 2 YEAR ;
```

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL use `TIMESTAMPADD` function:

```
SELECT ID, Product, make_date, order_datetime
FROM `tbl_order`
WHERE make_date > TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, 2, order_datetime)
OR make_date < TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, -2, order_datetime)
```